# No source available for "mysql_fetch_row() at 0x7ffff78cc6a5"

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse

So, I am building this c++ application. I am working on ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and with latest Eclipse. I have succesfully connected the database through [this](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-capi-tutorial.html) link
This is the code.

```
mysql_query(connection," INSERT INTO IdItems(Id, Items ) VALUES (4,19;)");

printf("%ld IdItems Row(s) Updated!\n",
       (long) mysql_affected_rows(connection));

mysql_query(connection, "SELECT Id, Items FROM IdItems WHERE Id=4;");

printf("%ld IdItems Row(s) Updated!\n",
       (long) mysql_affected_rows(connection));

//SELECT newly inserted record.
mysql_query(connection,"SELECT Id FROM IdItems");

err2 = mysql_error(connection);
if (strlen(err2) != 0) {
    //**DEBUG RUNS THROUGH HERE AND THEN SKIPS THE NEXT ELSE BLOCK, so error here**
    printf("%s", err2);
 } else {
    //Resource struct with rows of returned data.
    resource = mysql_use_result(connection);

    string tempvar="";
    // Fetch result
    result = mysql_fetch_row(resource);
    cout<<result[0];
    tempvar = result[0];
```

At the last 3 lines, I get a No source available for `mysql_fetch_row() at 0x7ffff78cc6a5` error from the eclipse cdt application.

The problem is that the query returns the results perfectly on my sql database.

The most weird thing is that this similar query works on eclipse(on the IDTable):

```
mysql_query(connection, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");

printf("%ld IdTable Row(s) Updated!\n",
       (long) mysql_affected_rows(connection));

//Resource struct with rows of returned data.
err2 = mysql_error(connection);
if (strlen(err2) != 0) {
    printf("%s", err2);
 } else {
    //**DEBUG FINDS NO ERROR AND ENTERS the else block here.
    resource = mysql_use_result(connection);

    string tempvar="";
    // Fetch result
    result = mysql_fetch_row(resource);
    cout<<result[0];
    tempvar = result[0];
```

Comment: Why do you have backslashes at the ends of some of the lines? C++ doesn't require you to escape newlines, except in macro definitions.

Comment: That is right. I edited the question. I just wanted to see those lines more clear on my eclipse. Thanks for your answer. Can you help me out with this please?

Comment: Are you going into the `DEBUG RUNS THROUGH HERE` section? In that case, you never assign anything to `resource`, but you try to call `mysql_fetch_row()` anyway.

Comment: I edited the question again to reflect the fact that the second snippet of code works normally even though it is similar.

Comment: If you want my help, answer my question. Is the error code executing in the first snippet? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: The error code in that point is not being displayed. Not with printf, nor with cout. I do not know why. But if I remove the if...else block code then the program stops on the debug mode on the `cout<<result[0];` point and gives me a `No source available for mysql_fetch_row() at 0x7ffff78cc6a5` error.

Comment: It gives an `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now` error later on the debug code after all. Have you got any ideas for what it may be wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41013/discussion-between-barmar-and-george-kourouleas)

Comment: I think Commands out of sync happens if you start a second query without fetching the results of the first query.